# Connect to an Oracle database using php

Tags: php, oracle

I need to connect to an Oracle database server with system identifier PROD, using the login "scott" and password "tiger."

Can anyone help

Comment: I hope those aren't your real login details!

Comment: http://wiki.oracle.com/page/PHP+Oracle+FAQ

Comment: @marcog: Yes ...these are not real login details

Comment: @Pekka: I want to connect to oracle database.

Comment: Have you Googled this? Have you tried something? Do you have code and any error messages? SO is here to help, but not to do it all for you.

Comment: @marcog, those are the credentials for the "sample" database that comes with every Oracle installation. You must not use Oracle a lot? ;-)

Comment: @Stephanie "You must not use Oracle a lot?" - I have *never* used Oracle before. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to connect to oracle. That way you can also easily change between different types of databases without changes to your code, making it very portable.

But note that the Oracle driver for PDO is marked as experimental so it might be changed with later releases of PHP.

Note* Never tested PDO for oracle myself, but it's brilliant for other types of databases and makes you able to switch between different databases easily.

Answer (score 2):

this is sample extract from [TNSNAMES.ORA](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora):

```
MYSERVICE =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = database_hostname_or_ip.com)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVICE_NAME=myservice)))
```

This is sample script to connect and execute query:

```
$oracledb["host"] = "MYSERVICE"; # service name in the tnsnames.ora file
$oracledb["user"] = "myuser"; # username
$oracledb["pass"] = "mypass"; # password
$oracledb["library"] = "OCI";

$connect_id = ocilogon($oracledb["user"], $oracledb["pass"], $oracledb["host"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$statement = ociparse($connect_id, $query);
ociexecute($statement);

$result = array();
while(ocifetchinto($statement, $tmp, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_RETURN_LOBS))
{
  array_push($result, $tmp);
}

ocifreestatement($statement);

var_dump($result); # result is here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP function [oci_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) to connecto to oracle db